# How to store the select result to a new column from the same table?

Tags: sql, db2

I am using DB2 of IBM. I have a table 
`stockdb(date, close)`
I am calculating the 30 day moving average of it and store it into the same table.

```
alter stockdb 
add ma as avg("close") 
over
(order by "date" rows between 29 preceding and current row)
from stockdb;
```

Comment: Please could you give an example of the data in stockdb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without example data; I am assuming you have 1 row per date and the close is maybe a closing retail value or something for a store?

Could you achieve what you want by doing this;

1. Add the average column to your table - I've made it 9,2 decimal;

```
    ALTER TABLE STOCKDB                      
    ADD COLUMN MA DEC (9 , 2) NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT;
```

2. Update your table, adding the average values to that column;

```
UPDATE STOCKDB B                                        
   SET MA = (SELECT XMA                                         
               FROM (                                           
                SELECT "DATE",AVG("CLOSE")                      
                       OVER (ORDER BY "DATE" ROWS               
                       BETWEEN 29 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) XMA
                FROM RAKELLR/STOCKDB) Z                         
              WHERE Z."DATE" = B."DATE")
```

So you build your date and averages within table "Z" - calling the average row XMA;

```
    SELECT "DATE",AVG("CLOSE")                      
           OVER (ORDER BY "DATE" ROWS               
           BETWEEN 29 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) XMA
    FROM STOCKDB) Z;
```

Then you update you STOCKDB table setting the MA column to = XMA where the date matches;

```
UPDATE STOCKDB B                                        
   SET MA = (SELECT XMA                                         
               FROM (...Z...)                         
              WHERE Z."DATE" = B."DATE");
```

Comment: Yes, i figured out the same solution as yours. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this as a computed column because window functions are not allowed.  Use a view instead:

```
create view v_stockdb as 
    select s.*,
           avg("close") over (order by "date" rows between 29 preceding and current row) as ma
    from stockdb s;
```

Comment: thanks, but my main problem is i cannot store the ma into the original table

Comment: @edwardluo - then calculate it on the INSERT.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO stockdb 
( date, 
  close, 
  ma
) 
VALUES 
( 
  CURRENT DATE,
  1.00,
  (select avg("close") 
          over (order by "date" rows between 29 preceding and current row ) 
    from stockdb )
)
```

The values are arbitrary,  I could/should have used bind parms(?) just as easily. I noticed your table doesn't have symbol, open, high or low so these would have to be added if you alter the table.